# Services to operating systems

Tags: python, service, banner

I made a banner grabbing program in python - I get from an ip its services on ports like : 20,21,25,80 ..
I want to know from those sevices what os is on the server.
Is there a specific list of services for each os?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any services that advertise os, but if you want to use tcp fingerprinting, you can use [nmap](http://nmap.org), and there are [python bindings available](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/) that can be installed with

```
pip install python-nmap
```

Comment: Nice answer and nice app!